# How can I access ServletContext from WebSocketServlet?

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, tomcat7

Is it possible to access ServletContext from WebSocketServlet? I'm using Tomcat 7. I have not found any method that exposes a reference to ServletContext.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSocketServlet extends GenericServlet:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html

Generic servlet contains a method #getServletContext:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html?is-external=true#getServletContext()